# How can I manage specific setting profiles for different physical locations (office vs home)?

Tags: users, networkmanager, geolocation

On my KDE Neon laptop, I would like to have several profiles which encompass the settings for:

- network (Wifi vs LAN)
- display (including external displays via `xrandr` or display manager)
- audio outputs (internal vs. external audio device)

Is there a standard way to manage "profiles" like the ones above without homebrewing a custom bash script?

If so, is it also possible to automatically switch between the profiles based on (for example) the availability of certain WiFi networks?